# I have some problem with my homework. It's about stop the loops

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, break

I'm in the middle of my homework. And i can't find out how to do this solution.

I have tried to used the break under for-statement but nothing return.
The problem is "Complete the following program so that the loop stops when it has found the smallest positive integer greater than 1000 that is divisible by both 33 and 273."

This is my code that i have tried to do it

```py
n = 1001 #This one is required

while True: #This one too
    for i in range(n,___): # I don't know what should i put in the blank
          if i%33 == 0 and i%273 == 0: # I really confused about this line
              break # Should i break it now?, or in the other lines?
print(f"The value of n is {n}") #This one is also required
```

I don't know that i should put break in which lines (or i don't have to used it?) or i should created a function that called a minimum number of the list?

I'm sorry about my language and how silly i am at my programming skill
I would accept every comment. Thank you

Comment: Not your main issue but perhaps important: Your problem statement has `273` as one of the numbers, but in your code you have `237`.

Comment: Oh yes! I forgot to change the number!  Thank you for reminds me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already have a `while True:` loop, you don't need the inner `for` loop to search for your number, just keep incrementing `n` in the `while` loop instead of adding a new counter, when the number you're looking for is found, the infinite `while True:` loop will stop (using `break`), and so your print statement will be executed:

```
n = 1001  #  start at 1001

while True:  #  start infinite loop
    if n % 33 == 0 and n % 273 == 0:  #  if `n` found
        break  #  exit the loop
    n += 1  #  else, increment `n` and repeat

print(f"The value of n is {n}")  #  done, print the result
```

Output:

```
The value of n is 3003
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Now i understand how it work. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for saying it's homework! Makes it better to explain things in more detail than just giving an answer.

There are few things to explain:

1) n%33 is the remainder of dividing n by 33.  So 66%33 is 0 and 67%33 is 1.

2) For loops are generally when you need to loop over a defined range (not always, but usually).  E.g. "add up the first 100 integers".  A while loop makes more sense here.  It will definitely terminate, because at some point you'll get to 33 * 237.

3) if i%33 == 0 and i%237 == 0: means we want to do something when the number can be divided evenly (no remainder) by both 37 and 237.

```
n=1001
while True:
    if n%33==0 and n%237==0:
        print(n)
        break
    n+=1
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! Now i understand more cleary

Answer (score 1):

A for loop will not help you here, because you don't know when to end the loop. You usually use for loops when the range of things you want to loop over is already known.

Instead, do the following:

before starting your `while: True` loop: set `i` to 0,

then increase `i` with 1 every time to the loop

also, don't forget to stop the loop when `i>1000`!

Comment: Thank you for replied me. Well the line 1,3 and the last one are required for this work so i can’t remove or add any code between them. By the way thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Well you could still use a `for` loop, as long as the upper limit is at least as high as the maximum possible result. The result would be in `i`, not in n, and the `for` loop will suffice, not an additional `while` loop. The `for` loop will break when the remainder when dividing by both 33 and 237 is zero (i.e. they are both factors).

```
n = 1001 #This one is required

for i in range(n, 33 * 237 + 1): # I don't know what should i put in the blank
    if i % 33 == 0 and i % 237 == 0: # I really confused about this line
        break #
print(f"The value of i is {i}") #This one is also required
```

You could also use a while loop and use the same logic for the condition. In this case we test that at least one is not a factor and continue the loop until both 33 and 237 are evenly divisible into i.

```
n = 1001 #This one is required

i = n
while i % 33 or i % 237:
    i += 1
print(f"The value of i is {i}")
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation!  I really appreciate it!